# I deployed a new version of my website with Next.Js, but we keep getting the old version (developed with Nuxt.js) when accessing it?

Tags: caching, deployment, next.js, nuxt.js, host

We have developed a new website and deployed it in the same domain we were using before, but the browser keeps loading the cached version of it. I know we could clean our cache to see the new version, but we would need all of our older clients to do it too. We would like to make our new website load on all of our clients browsers automatically, without needing all of them to clean their caches in order to see it. Is it possible?

Our older website was developed using Nuxt.Js and our new website is using Next.Js. Also, we have our domain on Hostgator, and we are using google cloud to host and map it to the domain. We have mapped our new website to the domain about three weeks ago.

Totally appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: Not enough context/info given here. What did you tried so far? Cleaned/invalidated the cache?

Comment: Well, I haven't tried much. I haven't cleaned my cache, because I guess that would solve the problem only for me. I wanted a way to let all the people who have already accessed our website before to load our new version. I noticed that if I open the website on an anonymous tab, the correct version loads in. Also, if I search my website on google and click on the arrow located at the right of my website on the search result, and click on "Cached", somehow, the current version loads in, not the older one. I don't know whats happening.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.